# Playwright request.post - custom headers

Tags: playwright

I am looking at playwright to send a few API calls, however I need to add a custom header.

I have tried

```
const apiResponse = await request.post(URL, {
headers: {
'custom': 'value'
},
{
body: bodyData
}
```

however, this is not accepted.

I also have tried axios, which does work, however takes 20 seconds to resolve the call - while postman is taking only 5 (which is why I am trying the native playwright method)

Anyone know how to set a custom header (all answers I have seen refer to browsers)

Comment: What custom header do you actually want to add? What error do you get when you say it's "not accepted"? Axios doesn't do anything special, just makes a plain old HTTP request, so I don't see any good reason it'd take any longer than any other library. If anything, I'd think it'd be faster than Playwright. A [mcve] would be useful here. Thanks.